# Check if SQL Connection is Open or Closed

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlconnection

How do you check if it is open or closed I was using

```
 if (SQLOperator.SQLCONNECTION.State.Equals("Open"))
```

however, even the State is 'Open' it fails on this check.

Comment: This question and all the answers don't really make any sense: `SqlConnection.State` just tells you whether the connection has been opened in the past, it does not tell you if the server is actually available. And it isn't necessary anyway, you just need to create a new connection, and dispose afterwards with `using`

Answer (score 217):

You should be using [SqlConnection.State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.state.aspx)

e.g,

```
using System.Data;

if (myConnection != null && myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
   // do something
   // ...
}
```

Comment: +1 exactly - use the `SqlConnectionState` enum as an enum and not turn it into a string.....

Comment: Should've added `using System.Data;` in the answer, IMHO.  I forgot this namespace (had `using System.Data.SqlClient`) and couldn't figure out how to get `ConnectionState` as a keyword until I added it.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Does this work if the *server* (or something between the local machine and the server) closed the connection?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to say `if (myConnection == null || myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { //Connection is closed } else { //Connection is open in some way }`?  This way if the connection is null it's also "closed".

Answer (score 61):

Here is what I'm using:

```
if (mySQLConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    mySQLConnection.Close();
    mySQLConnection.Open();
}
```

The reason I'm not simply using:

```
if (mySQLConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    mySQLConnection.Open();
}
```

Is because the ConnectionState can also be:

```
Broken, Connnecting, Executing, Fetching
```

In addition to

```
Open, Closed
```

Additionally Microsoft states that Closing, and then Re-opening the connection "will refresh the value of State."
See here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.state(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.state%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You should test if ``mySQLConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open && mySQLConnection.State != ConnectionState.Connecting`` to avoid resets with slow connections, shouldn't you?

Comment: @caligari While true, no guarantee exists for DbConnection, so if programming to the abstract DbConnection, be careful.

Comment: I personally think this is the kind of problem you solve by avoiding.  I can maybe see the use case for this code snippet in a stateful application layer, but never on the Web?

Comment: John, that is exactly the use case for this code. Code running a server application that could be serving pages, connecting to another REST server whatever. I don't see any case where I would connect to a server database in the client side code in a web application.

Comment: There is one giant caveats with that: 1) with Local Storage now becoming a thing, sooner or later (already?) web apps that use local storage are going to be using a database in that storage. If not now, they will shortly. The other thing here is, my code probably isn't properly generalized to be used in a large application. My main focus is embedded programming, so I'm still learning on the server side.

Comment: I am trying to use the above code but it keeps saying connection is open. What I would like to do is check if connection is open for my application only...

Comment: if  (connection != null && connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                                connection.Open();

Answer (score 31):

The .NET documentation says: *State Property: A bitwise combination of the ConnectionState values*

So I think you should check

```
!myConnection.State.HasFlag(ConnectionState.Open)
```

instead of

```
myConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open
```

because State can have multiple flags.

Comment: I wonder why this is enum with flags. Since the value of Close item of this enum is zero then State.HasFlag(ConnectionState.Close) will return true for any value. For me it means that i should check as "!= Close"

Comment: Open a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483542/net-state-of-db-connection

Comment: NOTE: I feel it's necessary to mention that Ivan's link mentions that you SHOULD NOT use this as flags. See this specific answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35484965/2499090

Answer (score 13):

Check if a MySQL connection is open

```
ConnectionState state = connection.State;
if (state == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    connection.Open();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of returning always true? At this point, make the method void. Only, check if the connection is not open and if so open it. And... why writing 2 times `return true;` ? put it in the end of the method, outside the `if`/`else`!

Comment: In case of network problems these would give a wrong answer.
you cannot be sure that open will indeed open.

Comment: @user613326 actually, it wouldn't. There is no error handling in the example code, so any problems while connecting will simply throw and leave you to handle the exception. The returned value is therefore correct.

Answer (score 8):

you can also use this

```
if (SQLCON.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
     SQLCON.Open();
}
```

Comment: `using System.Data;` for anyone that didn't know, or didn't know why it wasn't working

Answer (score 7):

This code is a little more defensive, before opening a connection, check state. 
If connection state is Broken then we should try to close it. Broken means that the connection was previously opened and not functioning correctly.
The second condition determines that connection state must be closed before attempting to open it again so the code can be called repeatedly.

```
// Defensive database opening logic.

if (_databaseConnection.State == ConnectionState.Broken) {
    _databaseConnection.Close();
}

if (_databaseConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
    _databaseConnection.Open();
}
```

Comment: Just being a little more defensive.

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).

Answer (score 4):

To check the database connection state you can just simple do the following

```
if(con.State == ConnectionState.Open){}
```

Answer (score 4):

To check OleDbConnection State use this:

```
if (oconn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    oconn.Close();
}
```

`State` return the `ConnectionState`

```
public override ConnectionState State { get; }
```

Here are the other `ConnectionState` enum

```
public enum ConnectionState
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The connection is closed.
        Closed = 0,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The connection is open.
        Open = 1,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The connection object is connecting to the data source. (This value is reserved
        //     for future versions of the product.)
        Connecting = 2,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The connection object is executing a command. (This value is reserved for future
        //     versions of the product.)
        Executing = 4,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The connection object is retrieving data. (This value is reserved for future
        //     versions of the product.)
        Fetching = 8,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The connection to the data source is broken. This can occur only after the connection
        //     has been opened. A connection in this state may be closed and then re-opened.
        //     (This value is reserved for future versions of the product.)
        Broken = 16
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only valid way to check the status of a connection is to execute a simple query (Ex. Select top 1 *yourfield* from *Table* in SqlServer
or
Select *yourfield* from *Table* limit 1 in mysql).
I think that is the only valid system to test the connection status.
If you don't believe me, try this in debug:
Put a breakpoint just after the if condition

```
if (oconn.State == ConnectionState.Open){
        oconn.Close(); //breakpoint here
    }
```

Make the program go all the way to the breakpoint.
Now, unplug the lan cable or switch off your wireless or stop the sqlserver or mysql services, returns the compiler to the previous statement and retest the connection. It will still be open.
Until you perform any operation on database, the connection will always appear open.

Answer (score 0):

```
is_connected();
```

This returns a boolean value if the value is `false` connection is still established. If value is `true`, the connection has been closed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I beg to differ on testing only the connection status.
The State property returns the last state detected by the connection but doesn't return the state of the connection at that moment.
Let me explain better with an example.
Let's do a simple test with a console application.
Let's create our connection to the db and execute it but not before putting a break point immediately after testing the State property.
Well, if we run the application and the compiler stops on our break point, we try to physically disconnect the network cable or disable the wireless (that is, we create an unexpected physical interruption). Without restarting the application, we return our debug cursor to the point where the application tests the connection status. You will therefore notice that the connection is still open, causing an error following the attempt to recover a possible Select.
So in my opinion, the only way to actually test if the connection is open and working is to make a simple select call right after testing the connection status. "Select 1" for example.
By doing so, our application is forced to query the database and verify the actual connection.
Here is the necessary code:

```
public bool TestConnection (SqlConnection conn)
{
    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) //Check State
    {
        try
        {
            //this is the most important part of testing the connection
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select 1", conn);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Dispose();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I use the following manner `sqlconnection.state`

```
if(conexion.state != connectionState.open())
   conexion.open();
```

Comment: `connectionState.open()` doesn't exist; did you mean `ConnectionState.Open`?