# .NET State of DB Connection

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, database-connection

When you manage database connection manually you always open and close it. Sometimes you need to check if connection has some state before do some action.
A classic situation is check for not Closed state before close connection.
Something like

```
if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
    connnection.Close();
```

As [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate(v=vs.110).aspx) states the ConnectionState is enum WITH FLAGS. It means that connection state can have different states at same time. May be Broken+Closed or something else...

If you decompile System.Data.ConnectionState enum you will see

```
[Flags]
public enum ConnectionState
{
    Closed = 0,
    Open = 1,
    Connecting = 2,
    Executing = 4,
    Fetching = 8,
    Broken = 16,
}
```

The value of Closed item is ZERO. It means that following is always true:

```
connection.State.HasFlag(ConnectionState.Closed)
```

So. Any suggestions why does this enum have Flags attribute? Or (if this enum must be Flags) why does Closed item have 0 value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe in the original .NET 1.1 implementation they planed on making it a flags based enum, However I don't think that is how the current implementation is used if you look at the note [in the remarks section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)

> **Note:**
>   The values in this enumeration are not designed to be used as a set of flags.

You don't need to check for flags it is safe to do a direct `==` test. They did not remove the `Flags` attribute because it would break binary compatibility with .NET 1.1 which they won't do.

Comment: Beat me!!! How can i skip this. I've seen this page twice before ask))) No questions.

Answer (score 2):

The **[Flags]** attribute on an enum allows you to assign multiple values to your enum at once, which is not possible otherwise. You can do this with bitwise manipulations, meaning you can store an enum with A and C set (both at once), not just A and not just C.

In this case it may sometime mean that the ConnectionState is **Open** and **Executing**.

The value of **Closed** is assigned zero so that it may not ever mean that the ConnectionState is Closed as well as Open.

[This post](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-flags) will provide more clarifications on this matter.

Comment: I got your idea. But Closed is significant state that programmer check. I mean then enum should be coded as enum ConnectionState { Undefined = 0, Closed =1.... }. Closed is not an Undefined, Unknown state. Closed is known and defined state, which explicitly assigned at other System.Data code, when connection close

Comment: I must check "!= Closed", But "HasFlag(Open)". Does not this ugly for you?

Comment: You are damn right! As per [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx) we must use HasFlag only for non-zero values of the enum type. Quoting from the linked article:

**If the underlying value of flag is zero, the method returns true. If this behavior is not desirable, you can use the Equals method to test for equality with zero and call HasFlag only if the underlying value of flag is non-zero, as the following example illustrates.**

Comment: Then I have to know that Closed is "undefined" enum element. How can I know this? Only decompile... It's unfair! =) What if it was an unmanaged code, C++ for example. For me, it's a little API failure

Comment: I think HasFlag is a generalized implementation, which probably fails in this specific context. You can report this to the .NET Framework guys and see what do they come up with :)

Answer (score 0):

Zero means that nothing is selected. 
In case of Open 00001, In case Of Connecting 00010, In case of Open AND Connection 00011 ....

```
0 0 0 0 0 
B F E C O 

Open = 1,
Connecting = 2,
Executing = 4,
Fetching = 8,
Broken = 16,
```

Comment: You mean that logic here is "if not other state then closed". Ok, but then why it has flag attribute and not used as constants? For multiple other states? Hm....

Comment: I didn't mean to upvote that. Can I revoke it? How? EDIT: Vote revoked :P